# Showing that Laplacian operator is invariant under conformal mapping

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

From my PDE class:

> suppose that $\Delta u = 0$ for $u(x_1,\dots,x_d)$. Then show
> $$\Delta\left[|x|^{2-d}u\left(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\right)\right] = 0$$
>
> Furthermore when $d=2$, $\Delta$ is invariant under conformal
> transformations.

I have tried expanding this using the identity $\Delta(\phi\psi) = \phi\Delta\psi + \psi\Delta\phi + 2 \nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\phi$. I have managed to compute

$$\nabla\left[|x|^{2-d}\right] = x(2-d)|x|^{-d}$$
$$\Delta\left[|x|^{2-d}\right] = d(2-d)|x|^{-d}$$

But the expressions for the other term turn out quite messy

$$\nabla\left[u(y)\right] = -\frac{2x(x\cdot\nabla u)(y)}{|x|^4} + \frac{1}{|x|^2}(\nabla u) (y)$$
$$\Delta\left[u(y)\right] = -\frac{2d(x\cdot\nabla u)(y)}{|x|^4} - \frac{2}{|x|^6} ((x\cdot\nabla)(\nabla u))(y)\cdot x$$

Where $y=\frac{x}{|x|^2}$. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about proving this idenetity or if the above expressions are even correct.

For the second statement in the case where $d=2$ the above identity becomes

$$\Delta\left[u\left(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\right)\right] = 0$$

If we consider $x=z$ as a complex number we have

$$\Delta\left[u\left(\bar z^{-1}\right)\right] = 0$$

Since any conformal mapping is locally a mobius transform. I think this means that combining this property and invariance of $\Delta$ under scaling/translation, we get an invariance under conformal mapping in general, but I'm not sure how to argue this.

Comment: There’s a mistake in your calculation of $\Delta |x|^{2-d}$ - it should be zero away from the origin, since it’s the fundamental solution for the Laplacian. It also seems like there might be a mistake in your calculation of $\Delta u(y)$, I’d suggest writing everything out in indices to avoid missing an application of the product/chain rule.

Comment: This is what I did to obtain the results above. If it's not too much, may I ask what result I should expect from these calculations? because I can't seem to get anything other that what I have put above.

Comment: I’d guess that you’re forgetting to apply the chain rule or product rule somewhere (I suspect forgetting to apply the product rule was the source of your mistake for $\Delta |x|^{2-d}$, which should be zero, not $d(2-d)|x|^{-d}$). You should expect all the terms to cancel and to get zero in the end, as the exercise states.

Comment: Your calculation for the gradients of $|x|^{2-d}$ and $u(x/|x|^2)$ are correct, so you should expect  $|x|^{2-d}\Delta [u(x/|x|^2)] = -2\nabla[|x|^{2-d}]\cdot \nabla [u(x/|x|^2)]$ since the Laplacian of $|x|^{2-d}$ vanishes.